# Split Image using Skimage

Tags: python, split, scikit-image

I want to be able to fourth the image, using skimage.

All I can find is cropping an image, however I want to fourth it, not just crop parts out. I need to fourth it to be able to compare to the other images for symmetry.

How can I go about this?

One of my thought processes if I couldn't find a function or way to split it, would be to find the vertical and horizontal lines manually and then crop using these values as the slice indexes.

```
height, width = size(image)
vertical = height / 2
horizontal = width / 2
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scikit-image, [images are just NumPy arrays](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/numpy_images.html) so you should use NumPy slicing for this:

```py
from skimage import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = data.camera()

nrows, ncols = image.shape
rsplit, csplit = nrows // 2, ncols // 2

quadrants = [
    image[:rsplit, :csplit],
    image[:rsplit, csplit:],
    image[rsplit:, :csplit],
    image[rsplit:, csplit:],
]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)

for quadrant, ax in zip(quadrants, axes.flat):
    ax.imshow(quadrant, cmap='gray')
    ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

If, and only if, you are sure that the number of rows and columns of your image are even, you can get the quadrants with [`skimage.util.view_as_blocks`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-blocks):

```py
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks

quadrants = view_as_blocks(image, (rsplit, csplit)).reshape(
    (4, rsplit, csplit)
)
```

Comment: this is a great answer. A generalized solution (instead of quadrants, N subsets) would be +10000